# AssociationOverrides from JPA not working properly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Here's what i have until now:

Class PedidoProduto

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido_produto")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pedProd.pedido", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pedido_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pedProd.produto", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "produto_id")) })
public class PedidoProduto {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PedidoProdutoId pedProd = new PedidoProdutoId();

    @Column(name="quantidade")
    private double quantidade;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

Class PedidoProdutoId:

```
@Embeddable
public class PedidoProdutoId  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Pedido pedido;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Produto produto;

}
```

Hibernate is giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
```

If I delete PedidoProdutoId and PedidoProduto, it works perfectly. What is wrong with this mapping? I have other mappings that are exactly the same and they are working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. An entity involved in those mapping were not marked as @Entity.